# convert from sensor_msgs::Image bgr8 to a png file on disk

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the subroutine I need.
What is holding me back from converting the rgb image you send me is converting to a png file.
This is done by using cv_bridge to convert from ros to the cv space.

The problem is cv is expecting a const sensor_msgs::imageConstPtr msg

I only have a const sensor_msgs::image.
We need to use “boost” some way to make a new member. Do you remember the syntax?

void convert_image_BGR82PNG(const sensor_msgs::Image msg)
{

```
//Convert from the ROS image message to a CvImage suitable for working with OpenCV for processing
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
try
{
    //Always copy, returning a mutable CvImage
    //OpenCV expects color images to use BGR channel order.
    const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr msgIn;
   //  msgIn = msg::ConstPtr<msg>;
   //msgIn = sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr(msg);
   cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msgIn,"bgr8");
   cv::imwrite("jnk.pcd",cv_ptr->image);

}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
    //if there is an error during conversion, display it
    ROS_ERROR("tutorialROSOpenCV::main.cpp::cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
}
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220619/convert-from-sensor_msgs::image-bgr8-to-a-png-file-on-disk/) by [mpatalberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/23552/mpatalberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good or bad the code compiles and links.
I will need to check the routine at work:
This involved linking in boost  and cv_bridge also painful.

void convert_image_BGR82PNG(const sensor_msgs::Image msg)
{

```
//Convert from the ROS image message to a CvImage suitable for working with OpenCV for processing
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
try
{
    //Always copy, returning a mutable CvImage
    //OpenCV expects color images to use BGR channel order.

    sensor_msgs::ImagePtr itI = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::Image>(msg);


   cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(itI,"bgr8");
   cv::imwrite("jnk.pcd",cv_ptr->image);

}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
    //if there is an error during conversion, display it
    ROS_ERROR("tutorialROSOpenCV::main.cpp::cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
}
```

}

---

Originally posted by [mpatalberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/23552/mpatalberta/) with karma: 26 on 2015-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0